# using C# DLL in vc6

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-c++-6

I have a c# dll that i can call it in vc.net (VS2010), when i try to run to run same source code in VC6 it gives error on

```
 IMyTestDLLPtr pIMYTESTDLL(__uuidof(CMYTestDLL));
```

and following is the whole code of this small utility

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

// Import the type library in DLL
#import  "MY.TestDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

using namespace My_TestDLL;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   // Initialize the COM interface
   HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
   // Make a smart pointer to the EPASS interface in DLL
   IMyTestDLLPtr pIMYTESTDLL(__uuidof(CMYTestDLL));  



   // Pass Params to API  
   BSTR result = 0;
   hr = pIMYTESTDLL->DLLFunction(1, _bstr_t("11111111111"),  &result);


   CoUninitialize();
   // Display the results
   cout << result << '\n';  
   return 0;
}
```

Anyone please help how i can utilize it in vc6

Comment: error on "__uuidof" vc6 is not identifying it

Comment: Hmm, if you want to use the smart pointers then you *don't* want to use raw_interfaces_only.  Looks to me you mixed that up with the no_namespace attribute.  Which is surely why it doesn't recognize the class name.  Not quoting the **exact** error message is always a mistake.

Comment: yes i also think that it is creating issue due to smart pointers. Can you please suggest what should i do?

Comment: remove the `raw_interfaces_only` attribute (or replace it with `no_namespace`)